# Buttons that include html with Jinja?

Tags: jquery, html, flask, jinja2

I'm building an app with Python and Flask. I've got a dropdown button with two options. I want it so that both of these options `include` a different html in a certain div. Is there a way to do this with Jinja? I'm pretty new to web development.

Here's what I've got (that doesn't work) but shows what I'm trying to do.

```
 <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <!-- Split button -->
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Topic Modle</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    <li><a href="#lsa">LSA</a></li> <!-- I want this button to include vis_lsa.html -->

                    <li><a href="#lda">LDA</a></li> <!-- and this button to include vis_lda.html -->

                  </ul>
                </div>

        {% if #lsa %}
         {% include 'vis_lsa.html' %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if #lda %}
         {% include 'vis_lda.html' %}
        {% endif %}

    </div>
```

I've looked at the Jinja documentation for Templates but didn't find anything similar to what I'm trying to do. I'm unsure if I'd need jQuery for this instead? I don't know any jQuery, so hopefully I won't need it to do this.

Comment: You have a few options, most of them include JavaScript. The other one requires making each anchor point to a URL to renders the page with the requested include. There's no way to make HTML interact with Jinja directly, though.

Comment: @dirn, Do you think I should look into JavaScript or jQuery then? JavaScript might be easier for a beginner? Should I look into simple "if" statements for JavaScript and start from there? Not quite sure where to go from here. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: It depends on how you do it. If you want to use Ajax, jQuery will be much simpler than vanilla JavaScript. If you pre-render everything and just want to use JavaScript to toggle some visibility, jQuery becomes overkill.

Comment: @dirn, Alright. I'll check out Ajax/jQuery then. For just starting off, I want to toggle visibility BUT my ultimate goal is to dynamically produce and show the content on the fly, that's generated by the Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a form tag containing `type="submit"` in the dropdown then create a [custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters) that checks if the `request.form` value is either *lsa* or *lda* after which it includes the appropriate html file. The request variable is [available](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/templating/#standard-context) to Jinja explicitly.